# Is there a simple way to "extract" a list of reated objects from a django queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a rather complicated model setup:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
     pass

class Category(models.Model): 
    pass

class Discipline(models.Model):
    pass

class Judge(models.Model):
    pass

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    judge = models.ForeignKey(Judge)
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Of course, those models are incomplete, but their contents aren't important for the problem... Given a Tournament, I need to get the distinct "Category" objects, along with the "Disciplines" evaluated for each of these.

I have tried this:

```
eval_set = tournament_object.evaluation_set.distinct('category')
categories = [jdgt.categoria for jdgt in eval_set]
```

Isn't there a cleaner way? I feel like there should be a sort of "extract('category')" that I could call on the queryset...
Any ideas will be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
categories = tournament_object.evaluation_set.distinct( 'category' ).values_list('categoria', flat=True)
```

Read more on [`values_list` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)